# Issue in running sudo visudo command? visudo: /etc/sudoers busy ,try again later

Tags: 16.04, command-line, sudo

There is an issue when I try to run the command sudo `visudo` and the error was shown:

```
visudo: /etc/sudoers busy ,try again later
```

Comment: Try restarting the computer.

Comment: still it's not working.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lsof /etc/sudoers` ?

Comment: `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
visudo  9348 root    5uW  REG    8,1      755 9699545 /etc/sudoers
`

Comment: So you have other process editing the `sudoers` file.

Comment: First switch to `root` user in case that something went wrong: `sudo -i` then kill the other `visudo` instance: `sudo kill -15  9348` after that using your root shell try `visudo`.

Comment: again showing the same error:`mifi@mifi-Aspire-E1-572 ~> sudo -i
root@mifi-Aspire-E1-572:~# sudo kill -15 9348
root@mifi-Aspire-E1-572:~# logout
mifi@mifi-Aspire-E1-572 ~> sudo visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers busy, try again later
`

Comment: Why did you logged out from root? retry the process DON'T log out from the root you may end up broking the sudoers file and locking your self out without sudo access, instead of `-15` use `-9`.

Comment: yeah it is working now instead of -15 using -9 helped me out.

Comment: Good, I sent it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First find out which process is using `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
sudo lsof /etc/sudoers
```

from your outputs, seems it's another `visudo` instance:

```
visudo 9348 root 5uW REG 8,1 755 9699545 /etc/sudoers
```

so, start a root shell:

```
sudo -i
```

then run:

```
kill -15 9348
ps --no-heading 9348 || kill -9 9348
```

open another terminal, run:

```
sudo visudo
```

make sure everything works fine, then you can log out from your root shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem and can't kill the process then you can use some other editors like nano.

```
nano /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: that might work, but it's not a good idea to edit `/etc/sudoers` with another text editor as if one breaks it with incorrect syntax  (which `visudo` prevents) `sudo` will not work and one will not be able to fix it

Comment: I agree with you, but sometimes we need that if we have incorrect syntax in `sudoers` and want to fix it so `visudo` works again.

Comment: I am disinclined to test, but I don't think `sudo` works at all in such cases (`man 5 sudoers` says "The sudoers file should always be edited by the visudo command which locks the file and does grammatical checking.  It is im‐
     perative that the sudoers file be free of syntax errors since sudo will not run with a syntactically incorrect sudoers file."), and certainly one cannot edit `/etc/sudoers` without being root, so unless one has a way of becoming root without `sudo`, which is not usually the case on Ubuntu, one is in a pickle.